# Erlang: How do I allow more than 1024 connection with Mochiweb?

Tags: erlang, connection, limit, mochiweb

I tried to increase file descriptors max limit on GNU/Linux:

```
$ ulimit -n 999999
```

and I'm starting the server with `-env ERL_MAX_PORTS 4096`.

Whenever I'm using test util, after 1012-1024 opened connection I'm getting the messages "Closed: socket_closed_remotely" and "Closed: emfile".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my mistake.
I called `ulimit` for another shell.

Comment: the `emfile` should tip you off to that conclusion. See `man 2 open` and search for `EMFILE` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Try tweaking `max` option which is passed to `mochiweb_socket_server:start/1` from your `APPLICATION_web:start/1`, where `APPLICATION` is the name of your application; for example your application called `helloworld`, then you will find the function `start/1` in file `./src/helloworld_web.erl` which looks like:

```
start(Options) ->
    {DocRoot, Options1} = get_option(docroot, Options),
    Loop = fun (Req) ->
              ?MODULE:loop(Req, DocRoot)
    end,
    mochiweb_http:start([{name, ?MODULE}, {loop, Loop} | Options1]).
```

Modify call to `mochiweb_http:start/1` to include the option `max`:

```
    mochiweb_http:start([{max, 1000000}, {name, ?MODULE}, {loop, Loop} | Options1]).
```

Hope that helps.